# How to convert ArrayList<int[]> into int[][] in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on a problem in which I performed many operations on an `ArrayList<int[]>`. However, the final result should be of type `int[][]`. Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this? If you have a solution that involves streams that's good for me.
Consider this example:

```java
    public static int[][] findFarmland(int[][] land) {
        var result = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        /**
         * Here you find a code to find farm lands. 
         * @see LeetCode Problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-groups-of-farmland/ 
         */
        return //array based on the ArrayList result.
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I know is this:

```
arrayList.stream().toArray(int[][]::new);
```

A little use case:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
     ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list.add(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
     list.add(new int[]{4, 5, 6});
     list.add(new int[]{7, 8, 9});
     
     int[][] array = list.stream().toArray(int[][]::new);
     
     System.out.println(array[1][2]);
 }
```

Comment: this is slower than just calling toArray, i have found someone that measured this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012471/collection-toarray-vs-collection-stream-toarray

Comment: @Ofek Nice :) In fact I use this command for its elegance, I never questioned myself about its performances

Answer (score 0):

You don't need stream for that, just the function toArray:

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
//...
int[][] arr = list.toArray(new int[0][]);
```

The function toArray gets an array of E and return an array of E. (where E is the type of the list)

- if the length of the input is smaller than `list.size()` it creates a new array with length `list.size()`
- if the length of the input is bigger or equals to `list.size()`, it just fill it.

You can understand this with this psudo code:

```
public E[] toArray(E[] arr) {
    if (arr.length < size()) {
        T[] ret = new T[size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
            ret[i] = get(i);
        return ret;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
            arr[i] = get(i);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ofek, Your answer is really interesting the way that I tried to solve this issue by myself includes the use of for loop... Your answer is clearly better than mine. But can you explain it further. I mean the 0 in new int[0][].

Comment: @KotbiAbderrahmane the function toArray gets an array. if the array is shorter than list.size(), it creates a new array and fill it. if its longer its write the elements into the array. i will edit the answear so it will be more clear.

Comment: I would suggest doing `int[][] arr = list.toArray(int[][]::new)`  Then one does not need to worry about the dimension.

Comment: @Ofek, thank you for your explanation. In fact, I took some time to learn more about this. One great article I came across was this one https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-toarray-methods . As you said when toArray takes an argument that one will serve as an initial in-memory array. This last will not only be filled but also if its size wasn't sufficient a new array of the required length and the same type is allocated.